# Can you resolve Google Docs' comments by email?

Tags: google-docs, google-drive-comments

In Asana, you can complete a todo by sending a reply to an email about it with the email contents "complete". Can you do something similar to resolve a comment in a Google Doc?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such option in the received email which would allow resolving comments on the spot, so the answer is no, you can't. All you can do is to **Reply** or **Open** the document and resolve it there:

[image: 0]